# .iso program is stuck on notepad and can't go back

Tags: installation, 13.04

I downloaded the .iso program and didn't know what to do with it so i opened it with notepad. Will it still work on boot? If not, what do i do?Will notepad still allow it to run on startup?

Comment: If you didn't alter the contents of the file, you are probably ok. To be 100% sure, run a md5 sum against the .iso and compare it to the md5 sum provided in the download page. If they differ you are out of luck and you will need to delete the .iso and download it again. Then go on and research the answer @bodhi.zazen gave you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iso file is not a program, it is an image. You do not open it you install it onto a flash drive or DVD.

I highly suggest you read through

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

and

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you force a turn-off and continue again with a proper .iso burner such as [brasero](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/brasero) (inbuilt) or [mount it](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html)

fyi, an iso is an "image" of a dvd...more like a dvd compressed into a single file

and don't worry..just turn your pc off and restart it...there won't be any `gedit` (proper name for notepad in ubuntu) open

Comment: I did that, and it didn't work, but that computer broke.